# ImportError: cannot import name '_path'

Tags: python, python3, anaconda3

AzureのComputer Vision APIをPython(Anaconda3)で使おうとしています。
MSがgithubで提供しているサンプルコードをそのまま使ったところ、
エラーが出て、解決できません。

【コード】

```
import time
import requests
import operator
import numpy as np
from __future__ import print_function
# Import library to display results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
# Display images within Jupyter
```

【エラーコード(抜粋)】

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py in <module>()
 19 import numpy as np
 20 
---> 21 from . import _path, rcParams
 22 from .cbook import (_to_unmasked_float_array, simple_linear_interpolation,
 23                     maxdict)


ImportError: cannot import name '_path'
```

matplotlibが何か間違っているようなのですが・・・

【version】
matplotlib:2.2.3
numpy:1.14.2

Comment: 関連 issue?: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12979

Answer (score 1):

Windows10でAnacondaを使っている初心者です。
Spyder単体をアップデートした後、まったく同じエラーになりました。
原因はよく分からないままに下記を実施したところ治りました。

- Anaconda promptを管理者で実行して、下記コマンドを入力

  > conda update matplotlib